# Reducing number of attributes (classes of marks) in marked point pattern using R?

Tags: r, point, spatial-statistics

I have a marked spatial point pattern loaded in R (from Shapefile). This dataset has 4 different "classes" of marks: class A, class B, class C and class D. Each class of marks is categorical. One can imagine it as an attribute table, where each class of marks is a new categorical attribute (or column).

Now I need to work with the dataset using only class of marks A. Saying in other words, I need to reduce my dataset to have only one attribute, not 4 as before. Using `split()` does not work for my case.

What is the command for doing that in R?

Answer (score 1):

You have to treat the @data slot (the data frame) a bit differently to reduce the number of attributes / columns:

Set the working directory and load the right library

```
require(rgdal)
setwd("~/workspace/TEMP/")
```

Make a fake SPDF to work with, as OP describes

```
pts <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=1:5, A = 1:5, B = 1, C = 2, D = 3)
coordinates(pts) <- ~x+y
writeOGR(pts, dsn = ".", layer = "testPts", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

Read the SPDF as a shapefile

```
pts <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "testPts")
```

The data frame is in the @data slot:

```
str(pts@data)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ A: int  1 2 3 4 5
# $ B: num  1 1 1 1 1
# $ C: num  2 2 2 2 2
# $ D: num  3 3 3 3 3
```

What if we try to treat it like a normal data frame?

```
pts@data <- pts@data[, "val2"]
# Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  : 
# assignment of an object of class “factor” is not valid for @‘data’
# in an object of class “SpatialPointsDataFrame”; 
# is(value, "data.frame") is not TRUE
```

You *can* subset the slot by just indexing as if it were a vector

```
pts@data <- pts@data[2]
str(pts)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ B: num  1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: @michalb, does this work in your case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to subset your dataset using bracket notation. As an example:

> point_pattern <- point_pattern[point_pattern$A == 1,]

Comment: This will not work as expected on a spatstat ppp object. Please try to provide specifics in your answer rather than being overly abbreviated. In this case you would specify that before coercion to a ppp object you could subset the the sp object using bracket notation. Please also note that it looks like the op has a character column, that is likely being coerced into a factor, and that after subseting the column will need to be refactorized to drop the missing levels. This can be done using "factor" however, "as.factor" would not drop the missing levels.